# one-dimesional and two-dimensional measures

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ denote Lebesgue measure for sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, respectively.

Let $\phi$ be any function mapping $[a,b]$ into subsets of $[a,b]$. That is $\phi(x) \subseteq [a,b]$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Define the set $S = \{ x \in [a,b] \, : \, \mu_1[\phi(x)] > 0\}$ which is the set of points that are mapped to sets with nonzero one-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Then:

> If $\displaystyle \mu_2\left[\bigcup_{x \in S}\{(x,y): y\in
> \phi(x)\}\right] = 0$, then $S$ must be of measure zero, i.e.,
> $\displaystyle\mu_1(S) = 0$.

I thought I could prove this by contradiction asuming that $\mu_1(S) > 0$. That would mean $S$ is uncountable and $\bigcup_{x \in S}\{(x,y): y\in
\phi(x)\}$ is a union of uncountably many sets of points in $[a,b]\times[a,b]$ which project onto  sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with non-zero measure. It seems that an uncountable union of such sets must have positive two-dimensional measure but I can't make any progress to proving the contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to write a really long proof about constructing a lower bound for the area of a rectangle-covering for $\displaystyle \bigcup_{x \in S}\{(x,y): y\in \phi(x)\}$

but then I thought, "isn't this set guaranteed to be measurable if its outer measure is zero?"

Indeed, it is guaranteed.

So the indicator function of $\displaystyle \bigcup_{x \in S}\{(x,y): y\in \phi(x)\}$ is measurable too.

Now use Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think uncountability is useful here. Instead,  supposing $\mu_1(S)>0$, try constructing some $\epsilon>0$ and some $S_\epsilon\subseteq S$ such that $\mu_1(\phi(x))\ge \epsilon$ for all $x \in S_\epsilon$.